# When do I apply for a job while in my last year of school Major is Information Systems and a Minor in Real Estate

Tags: software-industry, job-search, internship, fulltime

I currently attend a 4 year institution and this fall and spring will be my last year.

I am currently looking for a full time position in the tech field, hopefully somewhere in the Software Engineer spectrum.

I have interned at one small startup my junior year working with excel, access, and VBA. And I am currently interning at a fortune 500 company as a developer both frontend and backend, with the hope they offer me a full time job.

I live around the New York Metro Area and don't mind relocating.
Planning to start applying in the fall as soon as I can.

A few questions:

Should be applying as an intern?

I don't fell like I am very strong in my data structures and algo should I be worried?

What positions should I be applying for?

I am extremely scared for this coming year, and feel like I am not ready for the shift. I will graciously take any tips and advice and criticisms.

Comment: There are plenty of software engineering interview preparation sites and books. Going through some of those would be the best way to figure out whether you "should be worried" and also gain the skills you need.

Answer (score 2):

> Should I be applying as an intern?

If you want a full time job then apply for a full time job and tell them your expected availability.

> I don't feel like I am very strong in my data structures and algo
>   should I be worried?

I don't expect that a company that would hire someone straight out of school would expect them to be an expert or to have any real world experience. You should set your sights and expectations on an entry level position in your chosen field.

> What positions should I be applying for?

Positions that match your desired career and experience level.